# Can't get the newly inserted record in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I having trouble with getting the new record when it recently added. When I refresh the page I get the recently added record.

Sample Code for getting record in IndexedDB:

```
get(id, storeName, callback) {
            var trans = this.db.transaction([storeName], "readwrite");
            var store = trans.objectStore(storeName);
            try{
                var process = await store.get(id);
            }catch(ex){}
            trans.oncomplete = function(event){
                callback(process !== undefined ? process.result : null);
                delete process;
                delete trans;
                delete store;
                delete go;
            };
            trans.onerror = function(){
                callback(null);
            };
}
```

I'm getting undefined error because it seems its not getting the newly added record. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It'll be great if you could share the exact error here

Comment: there is no error, it just returning undefined. I tried to add and fetch the added error and still return undefined.

Comment: Hey @rojan, it seems like you are using the Native indexed DB implementation. And in the native implementation works on event handlers not promises. You can go through this awesome documentation - https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/